# Not getting rssi after connecting to a ble peripheral simulated on an android device

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, simulator, peripherals

I have two android devices: Device A and Device B. I am running a BLE Peripheral Simulator on device A. I am running the Device B in BLE Central mode. I also have a BLE Beacon. With Device B I can connect to the ble beacon and request for rssi

```
BluetoothGatt.readRemoteRssi()
```

But when I connect the Device A which is running a BLE Peripheral Simulator from Device B (which is in BLE Central mode) I and not able to get the proper rssi with the same function. Its giving 0 in

```
    @Override
    public void onReadRemoteRssi(BluetoothGatt gatt, int rssi, int status) {
        super.onReadRemoteRssi(gatt, rssi, status);
        Log.i(TAG, "onReadRemoteRssi: " + rssi);
    }
```

Comment: What does status contain?

Comment: I have tried two apps for Simulating BLE peripheral. One is [BLE Peripheral Simulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.github.webbluetoothcg.bletestperipheral&hl=en). And the other is [nRF Connect for Mobile](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.nordicsemi.android.mcp&hl=en). I logged the status value. its BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS for both the apps

Comment: @Emil : did you find anything useful that might help ?